# Limit returned documents with Node.js & MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm attempting to limit the number of items returned with Mongodb.  I tried *User.find({limit:500}* without luck. What is the correct way to get the **last** 500 documents?

```
    router.get("/dashboard", function(req, res){
    User.find({}, function (err, allUsers) {
    if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    } else {
    res.render("dashboard", {allUsers: allUsers});
    }
    });
    });
```

Comment: Take a look at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-setOptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find more samples on https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Basically you add the limit() function to the query

```
router.get("/dashboard", function(req, res){
User.find({}, function (err, allUsers) {
if (err) {
console.log(err);
} else {
res.render("dashboard", {allUsers: allUsers});
}
})
.limit(500);
});
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it fixes the problem, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi Good luck